# SlidingDrawer source

Tags: android, android-view, slidingdrawer

I imported the code for SlidingDrawer from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.2_r1/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.java/) and created according attr.xml, the problem is, that in the source are still errors, namely fields mTop,mBottom,mLeft and mRight are not defined. How do I implement SlidingDrawer code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may kick yourself for not realizing the answer first

You can use a getter instead

For mTop use getTop()

For mBottom use getBottom()

For mLeft use getLeft()

For mRight use getRight()

Answer (score -1):

Sliding Drawer is drepraced, you might use another library easier to use : BottomBarDrawer

https://github.com/MartinRajniak/BottomBarDrawer

And for your error, it's because you don't add the handle id (button/imageview,whatever) to the slidingdrawer element. Like that :

```
<SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:handle="@+id/handle"
        android:content="@+id/content">
        <Button
            android:id="@id/handle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:text="ButtonHandler" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@id/content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </SlidingDrawer>
```

Comment: Well, I know it is deprecated, that is why I am searching for explicit implementation. I got the error already resolved, but because of missing fields the drawer acts strangely. I will try the library you have suggested. I need a drawer from the right not from the bottom though.